# What edge-set is required to make a non-cyclic directed disconnected graph initial?

Tags: graphs

Is there an algorithm to find the minimum set of edges required from a new node in order to make a disconnected directed graph initial?

Example -

input:

```
a -> b;
b -> c;
b -> d;
e -> f;
f -> g;
```

[image: input]

output:

```
n -> a;
n -> e;
```

[image: output]

Result:

[image: result]

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that it will be some kind of fixed-point function on the set of nodes, like:

    target_nodes = fixedpoint (rewrite (reverse edges)) (setof nodes)

Comment: What does it mean for a graph to be "initial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "initial" means connected and having a single source, you can do no better than adding an edge to each source.

Comment: That's true, so I guess I'm asking for an algorithm that will find the sources.

Comment: Take that as a programming exercise. The exact details depend on the way your digraph is stored. Use the fact that a vertex is a source iff its in-degree is 0.